# using template format in python

Tags: python, templates

I use this code to align the output

```
template = "{0:20}{1:5}"
print template.format("1","bread")

1      bread
2      cheese
```

but what if I want the output to be like this

```
1 .... bread
2 .... cheese
```

can any one help me ?

Comment: Have you considered adding dots to the template string?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [format mini-language specification](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples), you need to add `.<` before `20`. This would basically say `format()` to use `.` as a "fill" character.

Before:

```
>>> template = "{0:20}{1:5}"
>>> print template.format("1","bread")
1                   bread
```

After:

```
>>> template = "{0:.<20}{1:5}"
>>> print template.format("1","bread")
1...................bread
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try

```
template = "{0:2}.... {1:5}"
print template.format("1", "bread")

1 .... bread
```

If you want a variable number of dots, you might try

```
template = "{0:.<20}{1:5}"
print template.format("1", "bread")

1....................bread
```